# where to find LocalDB data location

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, localdb

I've made a local database using visual studio and i published the app and installed it , where can I find the folder that the data stored in to do manually backup or to restore data
any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Visual studio,

on the left side click SQL Server Object Explorer -> In SQL server node

you will see the local databases. For go to the location right click on a database or localdb Node and select properties. You can find where stored your localdb files.

[image]